# Masstransit In Memory Testing waiting for consumers to execute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, masstransit

So I've been trying to write a test for mass transit using the in-memory feature. I wondered what peoples approach was to waiting for consumers to execute. In the example below a use a sleep or I've also tried a while loop, but not a fan of either, any better ideas? I basically want to check that the consumer is executed.

```
[Fact]
public async Task SomeTest()
{   
     var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
     {
         cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("commands", ec =>
         {
             ec.LoadFrom(context);
         });
     });
     var address = new Uri(bus.Address, "commands")
     await sendEndpoint.Send(MyExampleCommand());
     Thread.Sleep(2000);

     //Check nsubstitute mock received 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the test harness features that are built into MassTransit. They should give you some good ideas of how to test them.

You can look at the harness tests to see how they should be used. Note that they work with any test framework, not just NUnit.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.Tests/Testing/ConsumerTest_Specs.cs

The [Testing](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html) documentation explains how to use the test harnesses.